# Is it possible to recreate erlang's :math functions as elixir macros?

Tags: erlang, elixir, metaprogramming

I am in the process of creating a macro that will calculate the distance between two sets of lat-long values.

```
iex()> calc_distance(posA, posB)
2  # distance is in km
```

At the moment this is working similar to a regular function. The reason I would like it to become a macro is so that I can use it in a guard clause.
e.g.

```
fn(posA, posB) when calc_distance(posA, posB) < 10 -> "close enough" end
```

However, for the macro to be used in a guard clause it has to "[follow the rules](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/guards.html#list-of-allowed-expressions)". This means that many functions and operators are not allows to be used.

My initial macro looked like so...

```
defmacro calc_distance(ll1, ll2) do
  quote do
    lat1 = elem(unquote(ll1), 0)
    long1 = elem(unquote(ll1), 1)
    lat2 = elem(unquote(ll2), 0)
    long2 = elem(unquote(ll2), 1)

    v = :math.pi / 180
    r = 6372.8

    dlat  = :math.sin((lat2 - lat1) * v / 2)
    dlong = :math.sin((long2 - long1) * v / 2)
    a = dlat * dlat + dlong * dlong * :math.cos(lat1 * v) * :math.cos(lat2 * v)
    res = r * 2 * :math.asin(:math.sqrt(a))
    res
  end
end
```

I have begun making it "guard clause friendly" by removing all variables that were being defined in the macro.

```
defmacro calc_distance(ll1, ll2) do
  quote do
    :math.sin((elem(unquote(ll2), 1) - elem(unquote(ll1), 1)) * (3.141592653589793 / 180) / 2)
    |> square()
    |> Kernel.*(:math.cos(elem(unquote(ll1), 0) * (3.141592653589793 / 180)))
    |> Kernel.*(:math.cos(elem(unquote(ll2), 0) * (3.141592653589793 / 180)))
    |> Kernel.+(square(:math.sin((elem(unquote(ll2), 0) - elem(unquote(ll1), 0)) * (3.141592653589793 / 180) / 2)))
    |> :math.sqrt()
    |> :math.asin()
    |> Kernel.*(2)
    |> Kernel.*(6372.8)
  end
end
```

This still works as a macro but is still giving an error when I try to use it as a guard clause because of the `:math` functions being used.

If I could write my own version of this functions as macros this would solve the issue.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how might I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to implement this as a guard test.

Or well, it is possible if you allow for loss of accuracy: [this approximation of the sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula) could be implemented using only operations allowed in guards.

But most likely, in your program accuracy is a higher priority than saving a few lines of code.  In this case, I would probably make my function call `call_distance` and pass the result as a parameter to another function, which could use guard tests on the result:

```
def my_function(ll1, ll2) do
    my_function(ll1, ll2, calc_distance(ll1, ll2))
end

defp my_function(ll1, ll2, distance) when distance < 10 do
    "close enough"
end
defp my_function(ll1, ll2, distance) do
    "too far"
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It is incredibly helpful. However, the reason I would like to be able to define this function as a macro is because I was trying to figure out a way to run a complex query on an ets table. I was hoping to store a list of lat_long values in an ets table and select only the ones within `x` distance. From what I have been able to find, it seems like the only way to do this is with a guard clause. Do you know if it would be possible to query an ets table this way. Is an ets table even a good approach to the this problem? Thanks again

Comment: Right, for querying an ets table you could pass a [match specification](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html) to `ets:select`, and that would be subject to similar restrictions as a guard test - perhaps using a sine approximation would be a useful thing to do there? Or perhaps using [`ets:foldl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#foldl-3) to collect the matching entries (using `math` functions) would be fast enough. There is a performance/accuracy trade-off here, and I guess trying both and measuring is the way to choose the suitable way to do it.